# How can I make SQL*Plus exit when PL/SQL compilation fails

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

My script file has the following code:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE

@pkg_t.pks
@pkg_t.pkb
```

I'm running that script from SQL*Plus. If `pkg_t.pkb` is invalid I see:

```
Warning: Package created with compilation errors.
```

but SQL*Plus does not exit. I understand that `pkg_t.pkb` has a PL/SQL error compilation which is not the same as a SQL error.

What directive needs to be added so that SQL*Plus will exit when it encounters a PL/SQL compilation error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning you get isn't quite a PL/SQL error, or a SQL error. A PL/SQL runtime error would cause something like ORA-06550, which your `whenever sqlerror` would catch and the script would exit with that code. You're seeing a compilation error though, which is different, and that's generated by the client.

One way to catch it would be to check for errors stored in the data dictionary:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE

@pkg_t.pks
@pkg_t.pkb

declare
  l_errors pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*) into l_errors from user_errors;
  if l_errors > 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Stored PL/SQL has compilation errors');
  end if;
end;
/

exit 0;
```

If the package specification or body gets an error then the count will be non-zero and you'll see:

```
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Stored PL/SQL has compilation errors
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

You could also check object status in `user_objects`. If you want to check for a specific object you can name it, but that makes it a little less flexible; it may be necessary if you *expect* there to be other existing invalid objects lying around. Keeping it generic means you could have a separate script that you can call repeatedly to catch errors as early as possible, say `check_errors.sql` just containing:

```
declare
  l_errors pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*) into l_errors from user_errors;
  if l_errors > 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Stored PL/SQL has compilation errors');
  end if;
end;
/
```

And then you could do:

```
@pkg_t.pks
@check_errors
@pkg_t.pkb
@check_errors
```

You can make the script fancier of course and have other checks. And if your existing .pks and .pkb scripts don't already do so, you can add `show errors` so you'd see the actual problems.

---

A side note about `SQL.SQLCODE`. That will have the actual error code, e.g. 6550 or 20001. But most shells only allow error codes up to a smaller value, e.g. 127 or 255. That means the actual error code will 'wrap', so it's unlikely to be meaningful, but more importantly it's possible to have an error code that happens to wrap to zero - which means if you're checking the return code you could mistakenly think it was successful. For example if I'd done:

```
raise_application_error(-20224, 'Stored PL/SQL has compilation errors');
```

then the -20224 value would wrap to zero; SQL*Plus would exit with that code, but if I checked `$?` in bash it would be `0`, and it would look like it had been successful. Similarly -20223 would wrap to 255, and -20225 would wrap to 1 - bash would see both as error but would give no indication of what the actual error was.

So using a fixed value would be safer. I often just use `whenever sql error exit failure`, usually with `rollback` added, though that isn't relevant if you're only doing DDL.

Comment: check_errors shows all errors, that have not been fixed so far. Is there a way to see only those caused by previous script? I'd like to reset user_errors somehow.

Comment: @GerritGriebel - not really. The only way I can think to attempt that would be to record the script start time as a variable, then look for errors on objects created or modified (last_ddl_time) after that point, joining user_objects to user_errors. That's a bit out of scope though; maybe try that, and ask a new question if you can't get it to work?